# Дизайн Android-приложений с помощью CSS

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!

Так как я хорошо владею знаниям `CSS`, я хотел бы проектировать дизайн приложений, основываясь на `CSS`, возможно ли это? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать, например, [`NativeCSS Studio`](https://nativecss.com/).

Также, для разработки приложений Вы можете воспользоваться чем-нибудь типа [`Apache Cordova`](http://cordova.apache.org/) или [`PhoneGap`](http://phonegap.com/) – там Вы сможете применить `CSS`. Но эти платформы не дадут той гибкости, которую Вы сможете получить, разрабатывая нативные приложения.

И я **крайне не советую всем этим пользоваться**.